# How to ignore the safeArea while in fullscreen?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, safearea

I want to implement an image preview feature, but I encountered a problem: when the image is in full screen, even though the status bar is hidden, the safe area remains blank, as shown in the picture.
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzP54.png)
How to successfully ignore the safe area?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class PreviewViewController : UIViewController {
    var isDarkMode: Bool = false {
            didSet {
                updateBackgroundColor()
            }
        }
    
    var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            guard let image = image else {
                imageView.image = nil
                return
            }
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
    
    var fullscreen = false {
        didSet {
            guard oldValue != fullscreen else { return }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.updateNavigationBar()
                self.updateStatusBar()
                self.updateBackgroundColor()
            }
        }
    }

    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: .zero)
    let singleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return fullscreen
    }

    required init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        setupScrollView()
        setupImageView()
        setupSingleTapRecognizer()
        setupDoubleTapRecognizer()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupScrollView() {
        scrollView.frame = view.bounds
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        }
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }

    private func setupImageView() {
        imageView.frame = scrollView.bounds
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    private func setupSingleTapRecognizer() {
        singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        singleTapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSingleTap(_:)))
        singleTapRecognizer.require(toFail: doubleTapRecognizer)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapRecognizer)
    }

    private func setupDoubleTapRecognizer() {
        doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        doubleTapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didDoubleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateBackgroundColor()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        fullscreen = false
    }
    
    private func toggleFullscreen() {
        fullscreen = !fullscreen
    }

    @objc func didSingleTap(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        toggleFullscreen()
    }

    @objc func didDoubleTap(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if scrollView.zoomScale > 1 {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRect(scale: 2, center: recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)), animated: true)
        }
    }

    private func zoomRect(scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
        guard let zoomView = viewForZooming(in: scrollView) else { return .zero }
        let newCenter = scrollView.convert(center, from: zoomView)

        var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
        zoomRect.size.height = zoomView.frame.size.height / scale
        zoomRect.size.width = zoomView.frame.size.width / scale
        zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
        zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)

        return zoomRect
    }
    
    private func updateNavigationBar() {
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(fullscreen, animated: true)
    }
    
    private func updateStatusBar() {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
    
    private func updateBackgroundColor() {
        let aColor: UIColor
        
        if self.fullscreen {
            aColor = UIColor.black
        } else {
            print("Dark Mode Status: \(isDarkMode)")
            aColor = isDarkMode ? UIColor.black : UIColor.white
        }
        
        view.backgroundColor = aColor
    }
}

extension PreviewViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.zoomScale > 1 {
            fullscreen = true

            guard let image = imageView.image else { return }
            guard let zoomView = viewForZooming(in: scrollView) else { return }

            let widthRatio = zoomView.frame.width / image.size.width
            let heightRatio = zoomView.frame.height / image.size.height

            let ratio = widthRatio < heightRatio ? widthRatio:heightRatio

            let newWidth = image.size.width * ratio
            let newHeight = image.size.height * ratio

            let left = 0.5 * (newWidth * scrollView.zoomScale > zoomView.frame.width ? (newWidth - zoomView.frame.width) : (scrollView.frame.width - scrollView.contentSize.width))
            let top = 0.5 * (newHeight * scrollView.zoomScale > zoomView.frame.height ? (newHeight - zoomView.frame.height) : (scrollView.frame.height - scrollView.contentSize.height))

            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: top.rounded(), left: left.rounded(), bottom: top.rounded(), right: left.rounded())
        } else {
            scrollView.contentInset = .zero
        }
    }
}

struct PreviewView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var darkMode: Bool
    var image: UIImage?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PreviewViewController {
        let viewController = PreviewViewController()
        viewController.isDarkMode = darkMode
        viewController.image = image
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PreviewViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.isDarkMode = darkMode
        uiViewController.image = image
    }
}

struct ImagePreview_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PreviewView(darkMode: false, image: UIImage(named: "ppsd"))
    }
}
```

I tried using AutoLayout, but the blank space still exists.

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
```

I also tried to solve the problem through ChatGPT-4, but without exception.

Comment: add `.ignoresSafeArea()` after `PreviewView(darkMode: false, image: UIImage(named: "ppsd"))`

Comment: @Timmy Thank you very much, this method indeed works and eliminates the blank space in the safe area. However, I need to add .ignoresSafeArea() every time I call PreviewView(). Is it possible to modify the code in PreviewViewController?